# having issue with scrollTo() method

Tags: javascript, html

I want to scroll the image with mouse with in the div, but not able to find correct X and Y coordinate value to move the image.  below is my sample code .. I am able to scroll the image ***without*** DIV. Can someone help if i am doing something wrong here.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


document.onmousedown = function(){

var e=arguments[0]||event;
var x=getWindowSize()[2],y=getWindowSize()[3],mx=e.clientX,my=e.clientY;
document.onmousemove=function(){
var e=arguments[0]||event;
window.scrollTo(x+(mx-e.clientX), y+(my-e.clientY));


return false;
}
document.onmouseup=function(){
document.onmousemove=null;
}
return false;
}


function getWindowSize(){
if (window.innerHeight) return [window.innerWidth-10,window.innerHeight-10,window.pageXOffset,window.pageYOffset];
else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight) return [document.documentElement.clientWidth-10,document.documentElement.clientHeight-10,document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollTop];
return [document.body.clientWidth,document.body.clientHeight,document.body.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollTop];
}


</script> 


</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden">


<div id="mydiv" style="overflow:auto;position:absolute; height:300px;">
 <img src="img1.png" />

 </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work, what's wrong? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vlKJq

Comment: I do not not want to use the default scroll bar to move the image up and down. when i do the mouse down on DIV then image should move,  but it is not moving up or down..  when i remove the DIV tag then i am able to move the image with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Using the img with a mask to estimate correct percentage of sliding.

html:

```
<div id="div">
  <img id="img" src="http://www.fastcodesign.com/multisite_files/codesign/imagecache/960/article_feature/1280-army-of-luck-013.jpg" />
  <div id="msk"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#div {
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative;
}
#img {
  position:absolute;
}
#msk {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,0,.5);
  z-index:2;
}
```

JS:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var msk = document.getElementById('msk');
document.onmousedown = function(e){
  document.onmousemove = function(e){
  if(e.target != msk) return;
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var mw = msk.offsetWidth;
  var mh = msk.offsetHeight;
  var iw = img.offsetWidth;
  var ih = img.offsetHeight;
  // your formula goes here
  img.style.left = Math.max(-(x/mw)*(iw),-mw) + "px";
  img.style.top = Math.max(-(y/mh)*(ih),-mh) + "px";
}
}
document.onmouseup = function(e){
      if(e.target != msk) return;
  document.onmousemove = $.noop;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vlKJq

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works great with background image. but in my case it requires to work with Image tag.Is there way achieve this with IMG tag? Please help

Comment: it doesn't seems to be working for me. I'll try to modify this and try.

Comment: hrm...  what browser/OS are you using? this works on safari, firefox, chrome, opera on OSX

Comment: I am using IE10 on windows 8.